# Simple PingPong program and the String issue

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to make the program below scan a value of type String, and if it is equal to "Ping", the program will output "Pong!".

Unfortunately, I don't know how to make the scanner read the String type and compare it to the "Ping" condition.

```
package experiments;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PingPong {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String a = Scanner.nextLine(a); 
        switch(a) {         
        case "Ping":
            System.out.print("Pong! :D");
            break;              
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: `if(a.equals(“ping”)){System.out.print(“pong”));` And change `String a = Scanner.nextLine(a);` to `String a = scan.nextLine();`

Comment: switch/case statement works for me when using scan.nextLine().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String aString = scanner.nextLine();
    switch (aString) {
    case "Ping":
        System.out.println("Pong");
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println(aString);
    }
    scanner.close();
```

You are using the Scanner class for a nextLine and you are passing in the string you are trying to assign.  This will not compile...

Trust me when I say this for your benefit but you might want to try looking at some basic java syntax before asking questions on here because other people would likely tear you apart.

Comment: Be careful closing your `Scanner` as this will also close `System.in` and may not be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Change the line:

```
String a = Scanner.nextLine(a);
```

To:

```
String a = scan.nextLine();
```

i.e(1):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String a = scan.nextLine(); 
    switch(a) {         
    case "Ping":
         System.out.print("Pong! :D");
            break;              
    }
}
```

Another approach(2) is:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);       
String a=scan.nextLine();
if(a.equals("Ping"))
   System.out.println("Pong! :D");
```

Another approach(3) [ternary operator](https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018):

```
System.out.println(a.equals("Ping")?"Pong! :D":"Print here something else");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Scanner this way which returns a String

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String aString = scanner.next();
switch (aString) {
case "Ping":
    System.out.println("Pong");
    break;

default:
    System.out.println(aString);
}
scanner.close();
```